# Git blob too large when committing to Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, blob, node-modules, commit

I am running a ReactJS website using webpack and ran a build to push to my production server.  However, node_modules was being pushed even through my .gitignore.  I cleared the cash, committed and now node_modules is not being added to git (good).  However, when I try to commit some new code changes, I get the following error from gitlab:
[image]

I've ran git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep $BLOB_ID and am able to see the file.  I'm not really sure how to remove that so that I can commit to gitlab.  There are times when I see that same error and run the above command and no path is listed.  I've spent a lot of time with this and really have no clue how to resolve this going forward so I can push to my repos.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to remove the offending file [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) then replace the remote repository history (**BE CAREFULLY**) with the clean local repository.